# Why is my Apple Watch giving a beep at 22:45 every night?

Tags: apple-watch

Why is my Apple Watch giving a beep at 22:45 every* night? The sound is like a really short birdlike chirp, like three really short increasing notes.

There are no alerts or other visible things left; there is only this sound, and I think a slight vibrating feedback at the same time. I've googled all over but never found any explanation for this. OS is 8.6.

*Actually it's not really every night, I think it's like once in every other night.

Comment: I can’t wait to hear a field recording of this night bird!

Comment: Punctual chipmunks? Check all the apps on your watch that can set a notification, even ones you don't think you've ever used.

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but the sound is same or similar to the sound after successfully catching a song with Shazam. Maybe Shazam is sometimes moving on its own? (but there is no visual indication)